# CSS: Switch from vertical to horizontal if space permits

Tags: css

A common layout challenge I encounter is that I have a number of items that need to be listed horizontally, in a single row. If the viewport is too narrow for that, the items need to be in a single vertical column.

Wide viewport:

```
[ Item A ] [ Item B ] [ Item C ]
```

Narrow viewport:

```
[ Item A ]
[ Item B ]
[ Item C ]
```

This is easily done with flexbox, but **depending on the approach, I have one of these problems**:

- I need to manually define a breakpoint (media query) for switching between horizontal and vertical. As it depends on the number and size of the items and thus the language of the labels, this is prone to error.
- When there is enough horizontal space for more than one but not all items, the items appear on two or more lines.

I don't want this to happen:

```
[ Item A ] [ Item B ]
[ Item C ]
```

My assumption is that CSS alone can't solve this. Can someone prove me wrong? Are there alternative approaches to this issue?

Comment: Couldn't you write media queries ?

Comment: Edited the questions to clarify that breakpoint = media query.

Comment: *Can someone prove me wrong?* --> no, you are correct

Answer (score 1):

> I need to manually define a breakpoint for switching between horizontal and vertical.

It is the only one solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very quick fix solution and I would recommend you someone else's if you get a better reply but you could probably use media queries to do this and setup the items in a grid system.

```
container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas:
        'Item A Item B Item C';
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  container {
    grid-template-areas:
        'Item A'
        'Item B'
        'Item C';
  }
}
```

But this is very rough and there must be a better way of doing it.

I used these links as my reference so they'll probably be able to explain how to do this better

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp

Comment: Typically, flex works best for one dimensional alignment, grid for two dimensional alignment. Using grid doesn't eliminate the breakpoint problem either.

Comment: You could've just used `display: flex` + `flex-direction: column` in this case. No need for CSS grid.